# Install MS SuperPreview or Expression Web to other drive than C?

Tags: windows-xp, installation

When trying to install Expression Web SuperPreview or Expression Web to any other drive then C:, the install button is disabled.
This "feature" has bugged me since version 1 all the way through to it's current version 3.

WinXp SP3

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the disabled button? (is it grayed out etc)

Comment: Hmm, screenie I need to uninstall/reinstall it. I'll see if I can find some spare time tonight (takes quite some time and I'm using it).
The button is just grayed out until I change the install path to one on the C drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7 and 8 I would say install it as per normal to your C: drive, cut the directory to another drive, and create a Symbolic Link using the `mklink` command like so:

```
mklink /d "c:\Program Files\<Original folder name>" "d:\<New Folder location>"
```

On Windows XP it's a little trickier, because it doesn't come with the mklink command.

You can try one of the tools listed on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/117127/using-symbolic-link-in-windows-xp), such as the [Linux Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) to get access to a Symbolic link tool.

Symlinking out the directory like this works because as far as Windows is concerned, the files are still in the same place, so Registry keys and shortcuts are still valid, and at the same time you've saved yourself some space.

Comment: I'm not using this anymore, but if I would do so today, this looks like a legit solution. Still wonder why this is needed in the first place ...

Comment: Junction from sysinternals is a tool you can use for any windows so that does not come with Mklink.