# Straightforward, easy way to create symbolic links on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, symbolic-link

I need something supported *at least* on Windows XP and not requiring any new user downloads hopefully.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Symbolic Link on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 112):

Have you looked at [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)?

Also, Windows Vista introduced the [mklink](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/) command line tool to create symbolic links.

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
    /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
            symbolic link.
    /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
    /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
    Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
    Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link refers to.
```

Scott Hanselman has a write-up on it at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MoreOnVistaReparsePoints.aspx.

If you're speaking solely about Windows XP, I've only ever used the Junction tool.

Comment: Looks like another option could be the /J switch on mklink (like "mklink /J <JUNCTION> <DIR>"). Note that it isn't a separate executable, it is a command in cmd so if you're calling from PowerShell, you'll have to shell out to cmd (i.e. "cmd /c mklink /J <JUNCTION> <DIR>")

Comment: Wow junction works great. It creates a real symbolic link so even Cygwin will follow it.

Comment: `mklink` was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Why oh why did they reverse the order of the arguments from the age-old UNIX `ln` command?

Comment: @kbolino: Easy! Because they simply expect the open-source world to "catch-up" with them... ugh.

Answer (score 23):

There is a tool called **[Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)** which makes it easy to create symlinks to files, as well as an older type of link called a "Junction" (basically, a symlink to a folder) as well as many more exotic types of links.

[image]

Basic usage is simple: Navigate to the source folder, right click on the file or folder you want to link to, and choose the new "Pick Link Source" option from the context menu.  Then go to the folder where you want to drop the link, right-click, and select "Drop As" and then either "Symbolic Link" for files or "Junction" for folders.

*but*

BEWARE: One reason Microsoft makes it hard to do this is that junctions and symlinks can make it very easy to accidentally DELETE CRITICAL FILES!

In some versions prior to Windows 7, deleting a junction or symlink in Explorer would automatically DELETE THE ORIGINAL DIRECTORY as well!

I *believe* that this problem has now been solved... but of course I make no promises... be particularly careful with third party file browsers (if you're to the point of needing symlinks, I'm sure you're painfully aware of how hard the Windows 7 Explorer blows.)

But I digress.  My point is: be careful, do your homework and read the LSE documentation to find out how junctions and symlinks really work, and for gawd's sake BACK EVERYTHING UP before you start messing with junctions and symlinks!

Answer (score 9):

> the referenced directory should work
>   as if it had actually been added to
>   %PATH%, right

No, if you had C:\bin added to your %PATH% and inside c:\bin you created a Junction called c:\bin\anotherDir\ to point to c:\anotherDir\ so that you could run some.exe from the command line like:

```
> anotherDir\some.exe
```

This would not work since the %PATH% variable does not work with sub directories (symlinked or not)

you would need to create a hardlink directly to some.exe, so the hardlink c:\bin\some.exe points to c:\anotherDir\some.exe

So in summary I don't believe you can do exactly what you are asking. That said I do recommend [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) for creating Junctions and hardlinks. It offers more capabilities than most junction tools in a very easy to use windows explorer extension

Answer (score 7):

Try Symlinker a GUI tool to [create Symlink in Windows](https://github.com/amd989/Symlinker)

This application needs .Net Framework 3.5 to run (SP1 recommended) and as of 4/24/2015 this software will only work under

- Windows Vista
- Windows 7
- Windows 8 and 8.1

[image: Symlinker UI]

Comment: Can it create symlinks on Windows XP?

Answer (score 7):

### NATIVE Windows Vista, 7, & 8 COMMAND:

1. ***File Symbolic Link*** (default):

   - `mklink <oldpath> <newpath>`
2. ***Directory Symbolic Link***:

   - `mklink /D <oldpath> <newpath>`

Comment: This was already proposed as the answer 7 years ago.

Comment: This is inaccurate: Windows XP does **not** natively have a `mklink` command.

Comment: Vista was the first Windows version to include `mklink`, per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the version of NTFS that comes with XP supports symbolic links. NTFS6, which ships in Vista and Windows 7, supports symbolic links with the `mklink` command. The XP version of NTFS *does* support hardlinks, but these cannot span volumes.

Answer (score 3):

Create symlink in [Far](http://www.farmanager.com/) [Manager](http://conemu.github.io/en/FarManager.html): <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd>.

---

Here is also an insightful acticle on tree types of links in Windows (hardlinks, junction points and symbolic links):

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fgeektimes.ru%2Fpost%2F50878%2F

It lists several other tools to create links.

Answer (score 2):

Junction is a great utility but one thing to watch for is that junction points look exactly the same as ordinary folders in Windows Explorer.

Use 'junction.exe -s' on the command line to list all junctions in folders and sub-folders.

Answer (score 1):

**No need 3rd party software**. Just use the `.bat` file :

**https://puvox.software/blog/easiest-method-create-symlink-symbolic/**

Answer (score 0):

I used and recommend Junction tool from Microsoft SysInternals:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Example using cmd.exe:

```
junction c:\Program-Files "c:\Program Files"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a light weight software called "Easy Symbolic Link" that makes them easy to create with a right click. Try it here:

https://blog.afach.de/?page_id=589

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source tool called [SymlinkCreator](https://github.com/arnobpl/SymlinkCreator) that provides a minimal UI for drag-n-drop both files and folders to be symlinked. It can use both relative paths (if in the same drive) or absolute paths for symlinking. There is an option to retain the script used for symlinking.

[image]

Disclaimer: I am the author of SymlinkCreator. I created it for my personal use but then shared it with everyone.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.