# How do I choose the partition that I want to store my virtual machine on?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have installed the software VirtualBox on my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04, and I have also created a new partition for which I intend to store the files on. The purpose is to install Windows 7 as a virtual machine but I cannot figure out how to actually choose which partition I want to store it on. I have partitioned the secondary 1 TB drive in my laptop to one 950 GB partition as well as a 50 GB one which I want the Windows machine to be stored on. This partitions are all formatted and mounted without any issues. I would like to have my virtual machine stored on the following path: "/home/mihkel/VirtualBox" where my 50 GB partition currently is mounted.

The main drive which is a 120 GB drive which acts as the boot drive for my Ubuntu OS is almost at full storage capacity so I there would be no point in trying to install Windows on that one. To sum up my question; how do I choose the path for where my virtual machine gets stored?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this post?: [How to move VirtualBox files?](https://superuser.com/questions/256192/how-to-move-virtualbox-files)

To select your default machine folder location - Open VirtualBox and go to:

`File -> Preferences -> General -> Default machine Folder`

Also check your help menu in VirtualBox's various sections or this on-line Source:

[VirtualBox Documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Documentation)

Good luck!